# Is it possible to run .ipynb notebooks locally using GPU acceleration? How?

Tags: gpu

Every time I need to train a 'large' deep learning model I do it from Google Collab, as it allows you to use GPU acceleration.

My pc has a dedicated GPU, I was wondering if it is possible to use it to run my notebooks locally in a fast way. Is it possible to train models using my pc GPU? In that case, how?

I am open to work with DataSpell, VSCode or any other IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Nicholas Renotte has a great 'Getting Started' [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19LQRx78QVU) that goes through the entire process of setting up GPU accelerated notebooks on your PC. The stuff you're interested starts around the 12 minute mark.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to run .ipynb notebooks locally using GPU acceleration. To do so, you will need to install the necessary libraries and frameworks such as TensorFlow, PyTorch, or Keras. Depending on the IDE you choose, you will need to install the relevant plugins and packages for GPU acceleration.

In terms of IDEs, DataSpell, VSCode, PyCharm, and Jupyter Notebook are all suitable for running notebooks locally with GPU acceleration.

Once the necessary libraries and frameworks are installed, you will then need to install the appropriate drivers for your GPU and configure the environment for GPU acceleration.

Finally, you will need to modify the .ipynb notebook to enable GPU acceleration and specify the number of GPUs you will be using. Once all the necessary steps have been taken, you will then be able to run the notebook locally with GPU acceleration.